# Bot doesnt charge coins again and again || Loop repeat

Tags: node.js, discord.js

*Last question on my bot*

My bot transfer 200 coins to user if he spent 1 minute in the voice channel with the microphone turned on, BUT ONLY ONE TIME

Everything works except loop repeat. I need that bot will add coins to the user every minute, one after another...

Thank you very much to these guys for great help of writing code:

[federico-grandi]https://stackoverflow.com/users/7133466/federico-grandi
[cherryblossom]https://stackoverflow.com/users/8289918/cherryblossom

```
let voiceStates = {}

bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {

  let { id } = oldState;

  if (!oldState.channel) {

    console.log('user joined voice channel');

    voiceStates[id] = { joined: new Date() };
    if(!newState.selfMute) {
      voiceStates[id].timeout = bot.setTimeout(() => {
        coinAmt = 200;

        console.log('user earned 200 coins');

        if(coinAmt){
          coins[newState.id] = {

            coins: coins[newState.id].coins + coinAmt

          }

         }

      }, 60000);
    }

  } else if (!newState.channel || newState.selfMute) {

    console.log('user left')

    if (voiceStates[id].timeout) {
      bot.clearTimeout(voiceStates[id].timeout);
      voiceStates[id].timeout = 60000;
    }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout() only calls a function once after a certain delay. Use [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) instead to keep calling the function again after one call. You will have to rewrite the code and check the connected members of each voice channel every time the function in setInterval() gets called.